When hoving the mouse over a variable in a C++ project the Intellisense popup doesn't show if I run VS 2022 as an admin
I'm not sure if it's a setting that I'm missing, or what?
When I open a C++ solution in the Visual Studio 2022 as a standard user, and then start debugging it, the Intellisense shows a popup with the value of the variable that I hovered over. Which I use all the time.
But when I open the VS 2022 as an admin (which I need to debug this particular executable), and then start debugging it, the Intellisense doesn't show any popups when I hover the mouse over variables. I know that I can use the "Watch window" but that is not very convenient for me.
PS. I cleaned that project and also deleted the .vs folder. That didn't help.

Check your environment variables maybe?  How does a user and the admin's environment variables differ.  Possibly some include paths aren't set up right for the admin or something.

Maybe some VS settings are different between the regular user and admin? Try Tools -> Import and Export Settings to a file as normal user first, then as admin, then compare the files.

Based on your description, it seems like that it's a Data tips issue in break mode.
Did you install third-party extensions?
If you install third-party extensions with different roles such as a standard user or an admin, Per-user and administrative extensions will be loaded according to the identity role. Those extensions might contain errors or malicious code that affect VS. This may be the reason why IntelliSense behaves differently when opening VS with an administrator account and a normal user.
Here are suggestions you can check to troubleshoot the issue:
1.Open VS as a standard user and navigate to Tools > Options > Environment > Extensions, check/uncheck Load per user extensions when running as administrator check box and watch whether the intellisens pops up.
If intellisense does not popup with this setting checked, it can be inferred that a certain extension caused this problem.
You can refer to Per-user and administrative extensions to check your extensions installed in your machine.
2.Please start Visual Studio in safe mode to see if the issue persists.This switch prevents all third-party VSPackages from loading when Visual Studio starts, allowing stable execution.
devenv /safemode

Hope it can help you.

Thanks. I don't think I have a lot of extensions. I just checked. Almost all of them are from MSFT, except one, which is WiX Toolset extension. I also tried to do what you suggested, but the UI in that Options window is totally messed up. I can't click anything in it. This is how it looks: https://i.imgur.com/3lDy3qh.png

This probably has something to do the mouse hover not working - the UI magnification is off. I think I applied some setting to the way VS starts up because the resource editor in VS was messing up my projects (due to high DPI setting). The VS couldn't handle it. Now I need to figure out what did I do to have VS start up like that.... hmm.

OK, I found it. I previously added this registry setting: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers -> REG_SZ: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" = "DPIUNAWARE" to compensate for the VS resource editor messing up my projects when VS wasn't capable of handling high DPI. So when I removed that registry key, the Intellisense started working. I guess it's either feast or famine.

Hi @c00000fd, glad to hear you found the root cause of the IntelliSense issue. You can add an answer to share your solution. This will help other users who has the same issue and someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem. Just a reminder.
